# Can I tether a Motorola Xoom w/o 3G to my HTC incredible phone?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, tethering, motorola-xoom, reverse-tether

I am considering buying a Motorola Xoom and would like to tether it to my HTC incredible phone for internet when there is no Wi-Fi available. I've already successfully tethered my laptop using either USB or Bluetooth and am wondering how I could do likewise for the Xoom?

Do I need to root either device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your incredible will create a WiFi hotspot it will work with the Xoom.  You can test this with your laptop before buying the Xoom.